# Augmented Assignment

Tags: python

I am new to the world of Python and programming in general, and today I have faced a problem with augmented assignment. I unfortunately do not understand the code, and what `for i in range(multiplier)` and `answer *= number` does. I tried understanding it but I still don't really get the logic behind it. Can somebody please explain?

```
number = 5
multiplier = 8
answer = 0

for i in range(multiplier):
    answer *= number

print(answer)
```

Comment: It might be hard to understand that because the logic behind it is broken (zero times anything is always zero)

Comment: @wim, very true...

Answer (score 1):

> range([start], stop[, step])

range is a function that ***takes a number and return a list of number from 0 ... right through to the number you gave it as an argument***.

> BUT THE KEY TO NOTICE IS THAT IT WILL NEVER INCLUDE THE NUMBER YOU
>   TOLD IT TO COUNT TO

. Example :

This is an example of giving the function **range** 1 argument:

```
>>> # One parameter
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Here is an example of giving it two arguments where the first argument is telling the function what to start the **list it returns** at. The second argument is where it should end:

```
>>> # Two parameters
>>> for i in range(3, 6):
...     print(i)
... 
3
4
5
```

Here is an even **cooler** example where we use the third argument as well. This argument tells the function to count from **whatever number** you told it to start at, right through to **whatever number** you told it to stop at (just like the above to examples)... only now, the third argument tells it in what steps to count:

Like count from 2 to 12 but count in 2's:

```
>>> # Three parameters
>>> for i in range(2, 12, 2):
...     print(i)
...
2 
4
6
8
10
```

SO....

the for loop is just iterating through that list of numbers that is given back by the function **range**

so lets break that for loop in to pseudo code.

```
***loop***
for i in range(multiplier):
    answer *= number

***Pseudo code***
Give me a list of numbers
(not giving it a start value but only a value to end the count at).
The numbers has to be from 0 to multiplier (8).
so range(multiplier) -> range(8) -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
now you have a list
now you ask the compiler to go through that list.
you say : go through that list and everytime you at a new number, give it to me in the for of a variable called i.
then when you have i, you don't use it because i was just trying to loop 8 (multiplier) times... but now take the answer and add to it this (answer * number) ... this will happen 8 times because you loop 8 times
```